# class.upload.php issue with cropping

Tags: php, arrays, image

I have a PHP page that uses `php_class_upload`. All works well except that I'm having issues with cropping.

I pass the Left, Top, Right, and Bottom values all are there no issue.

**Log:**

> [27-Aug-2015 19:31:40 America/Chicago] top 52 ,right 239 , bottom 172 ,left 119

What I'm trying to accomplish is resize the image then crop it.

I have set up the following code for php_class_upload:

```
 $foo->file_new_name_body =  $new_image_name;
 $foo->image_resize = true;
 $foo->image_x = $_width;
 $foo->image_ratio_y = true;
 $foo->image_convert = png;
 $foo->Process( $structure);
 $foo->image_rotate = $rotate;      
 $foo->image_crop = array($top .','.  $right.','. $bottom.','.$left);
```

The image uploads okay and its resizes correctly. however the cropping is not applied. Based on the [GitHub](https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php#changelog) page .

I have setup the array to follow the example on the link above:

```
 $handle->image_crop = array(50,40,30,20);
```

Which is 'T R B L'.

I set mine up like this:

```
 $foo->image_crop = array($top .','.  $right.','. $bottom.','.$left);
```

I was googling and found this [page](http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm) and notice that they are not using a array but just passing a string like so (which I tried)

```
$foo->image_crop = '5 40 10% -20';
```

I also tried to hard code some values but no luck.

```
 $foo->image_crop = array( 0,100,100,0);
```

and

```
 $foo->image_crop = '0,100,100,0';
```

I think my issue is how I'm setting up the array but I'm at a point where I need help. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $foo->image_crop = array($top,  $right, $bottom, $left); use it for cropping points.

Comment: gave it a shot my no good same problem but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to call $foo->Process( $structure); last before the crop